# Android SDK Eclipse Google Maps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, maps

since 10 days i try to see a map on my phone.

i want to get a route from current location to another location..

I have the google lib,
I have the api key,
I tried the view with a fragment and with a Mapview,

I read more than 5 tutorials and watch 2 tutorials on youtube...

activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class GoogleNav extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_googlenav);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jk.johnknust"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    Damit Handys mit hohen Auflösungen (z. B. Motorola Milestone) auch die hdpi-Resourcen verwenden
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.jkjohnknust.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.jkjohnknust.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application      
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.Questlog"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.QuestDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sek" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.Navigation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nav" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.GoogleNav"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_googlenav" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="yes i insert my key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

error log

```
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782): Failed to inflate
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.jk.johnknust.GoogleNav.onCreate(GoogleNav.java:23)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5161)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
06-14 23:13:17.475: E/ActivityThread(10782):    ... 21 more
06-14 23:13:17.475: D/AndroidRuntime(10782): Shutting down VM
06-14 23:13:17.475: W/dalvikvm(10782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a4ce0)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782): Process: com.jk.johnknust, PID: 10782
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jk.johnknust/com.jk.johnknust.GoogleNav}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5161)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.jk.johnknust.GoogleNav.onCreate(GoogleNav.java:23)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    ... 11 more
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
06-14 23:13:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(10782):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Google Play Services is not properly added to your project, so the XML compile fails.  That's the error you're seeing about the XML file.

Comment: Reading the stacktrace is often helpful. The way to fix is there.

The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /

Comment: project properties -> android -> Library -> green symbol for google Services ..

the other way ... 

properties -> java build path -> libraries -> Add google services as Jar .. 

no reaction :/ same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the google play version inside your application tag

**sample:**

```
<application      
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.Questlog"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.QuestDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sek" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.Navigation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nav" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jk.johnknust.GoogleNav"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_googlenav" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="yes i insert my key" />


    </application>
```